# How to check ShellExecute command return(HINSTANCE ) code in QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

I am using Shell commands to start a process. My development environment is C++/QT Creator/QT Libraries and Windows APIs.

How can I handle the HINSTANCE return value?  if (hInstance < 32) code throwing a compilation error

```
    437: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer


    HINSTANCE hInstance = ShellExecute(0, QString("open").toStdWString().c_str(), Path.toStdWString().c_str(), 0, 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
   if (hInstance < 32)
      qDebug() << "Error";
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still struggling with this, here is a solution that avoids warnings:

```
int retValue = static_cast<int>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(ShellExecute(<etc>)));
```

See [When is uintptr_t preferred over intptr_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29800256/when-is-uintptr-t-preferred-over-intptr-t) for more commentary on uintptr_t

Answer (score 0):

You can use reinterpret_cast to cast the return value:

```
int retValue  = reinterpret_cast<int>(ShellExecute(0, QString("open").toStdWString().c_str(), Path.toStdWString().c_str(), 0, 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL));
   if (retValue  < 32)
      qDebug() << "Error";
```

while it also can lead to a warning:

> warning C4302: 'reinterpret_cast' : truncation from 'HINSTANCE' to 'int'

but at least it works.
In MSDN, it also suggest to cast to int.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx

'If the function succeeds, it returns a value greater than 32. If the function fails, it returns an error value that indicates the cause of the failure. The return value is cast as an HINSTANCE for backward compatibility with 16-bit Windows applications. It is not a true HINSTANCE, however. It can be cast only to an int and compared to either 32 or the following error codes below.'

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`ShellExecuteW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutew) has been [updated](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sdk-api/pull/858) since other answers were published. It now accurately describes error reporting rules.

The only meaningful operation on the return value is a cast to an `INT_PTR` type and comparing it against the value 32 or a fixed list of error constants. If the call succeeded, the return value is *greater than 32*.

The following code reliably checks for success or failure:

```cpp
auto const result = reinterpret_cast<INT_PTR>(ShellExecute(/* ... */));
auto const success = result > 32;
if (!success) {
    // The call failed
    auto const ec = ::GetLastError();
    qDebug << "Error: " << ec;
    // ...
}
```

This works, but `ShellExecuteW` is problematic for several other reasons. It is recommended to use [`ShellExecuteExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexw) instead, offering both better error reporting as well as more control.

Answer (score -1):

Compiled fine with mingw64, even with -o3 -s switches.

```
HINSTANCE _hi_stuff = ShellExecuteW(NULL, L"open", _stuff_to_open.c_str(), NULL NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
DWORD error = GetLastError();
                
if ( error == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
if(MessageBoxW(NULL, L"file not found!\ndo you want to locate it?" , L"Error" ,   MB_YESNO) == IDYES)
{
//do something
}
```

Comment: This does not follow the API contract for [`ShellExecuteW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutew).